# What is the equivalent in Ab tool for 100 threads with 250 loop in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, apachebench

If I have 100 threads with 250 loop test in JMeter how do I run the same in Ab tool?

Answer (score 0):

100 threads with 250 loops will execute 25,000 times in total.

[ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) -n define number of requests and

> -n requests
>   Number of requests to perform for the benchmarking session.

While thread number controlled by `-c`

> -c concurrency
>   Number of multiple requests to perform at a time.

So in your case execute it as

```
 ab -n 25000 -c 100
```